# Quero converter uma lista<qualquer tipo> para uma lista de tipo generico?

Tags: c#

Quero que uma lista de determinado tipo se torne uma lista de um unico tipo :
exemplos

```
List<usuarios> se transformar em uma List<T>
```

obs : não sei se isso é possivel
Ou uma Lista de maça vire uma `Lista<T>`
o motivo disso é que tenho um metodo que só aceita `listas<T>` eu queria que ele aceitasse qualquer coisa...

Comment: Gabriel, seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais como funciona as coisas por aqui.

Comment: Teria como [edit] e postar um exemplo de um trecho de código que tenha tentado aplicar essa idéia? (essa parte do método que comentou, e o código que deve chamar esse método). Seria bom que explicasse o que queria que acontecesse, e o que aconteceu de fato. Idealmente, um [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

O proprio `List<T>` já é um generic, basta você passar o Tipo como `List<string>` por exemplo e terá uma lista genérica. Caso precise de uma lista que aceite qualquer tipo pode usar o ArrayList ou o proprio List passando Object no tipo (`List<Object>`).

Comment: Olá, Stan; Seria legal se você pudesse editar sua reposta acrescentando um exemplo de código para ilustrar melhor. (Demonstrando que o <T> de fato é qualquer tipo, facilitaria para o autor visualizar)

Comment: Vlw Bacco pela dica